get home directory of all running apache httpd procesess
Below is the process dump of all running httpd processes.
$ ps -ef | grep '[b]in/httpd'
 wsadmin  8465  8463   0   Jul 13 ?           1:21 /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-model/bin/httpd -k start
 wsadmin 23234 18662   0 14:00:34 ?           0:01 /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-perf/bin/httpd -k start
 wsadmin 14098  6780   0   Jul 20 ?           1:07 /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-msp/bin/httpd -k start
 wsadmin 28824 18662   0 11:31:13 ?           0:03 /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-perf.web/bin/httpd -k start
 wsadmin  7380 18662   0 09:30:35 ?           0:03 /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-perf.myapp/bin/httpd -k start

I wish to get the home directory for each i.e /web/apps/perf/apache/2.4.52/https-perf.myapp for example.
I tried ps -ef | grep '[b]in/httpd' | awk '{print $8}' but like you can see the home directory  is not always the 8th column.
Thus, i need a  solution that would work for linux and solaris.
Solaris version:
uname -a SunOS myremsolhost 5.11 11.4.70.170.1 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
grep -Po option does not work for solaris

Under Linux, you can get the path to the executable (which is what you see in your ps output) from /proc/<pid>/exe. Does solaris expose a similar file in /proc? It's been decades since I've been on a Solaris system.

What version of Solaris?  And what do you mean by "home directory"?  Do you mean the full path to the executable binary that is running?  The current directory of that process?  Or the actual home directory of the user running the process?

For me adding just | cut -d '/' -f 2- would work

This should get the expected result :
ps -ef | grep -Po '.* \K(.*)(?=/[b]in/httpd)'

I don't have a Solaris system to test on.

I doubt Solaris grep supports -P/pcre regular expressions.

uname -a SunOS myremsolhost 5.11 11.4.70.170.1 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
grep -Po option does not work for solaris @Philippe
